# iOS Save file to non-private directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

Right now I am working on a project which uploads files from the system and I was wondering if it is possible to save NSData to a location that is not private. Basically when I save data right now the cooresponding url looks something like this:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../image.jpg
```

But when I get files back from the UIImagePicker the URL looks like this:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../image.jpg
```

How can I (if it is possible) save data to a directory not under private?

Just for reference this is the code I have to move files so far:

```
- (NSURL *)moveFileToTemporaryMemory:(NSURL *)url {
  NSError *readingError, *writingError;
  NSString *fileName = url.lastPathComponent;
  NSURL *tempURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()] URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&readingError];
  [data writeToURL:tempURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writingError];
  return tempURL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference -- `/var` is a symbolic link to `/private/var`, so both paths are equivalent.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a react-native project I'm working on and the RNFetchBlob module I'm using doesn't think they are :(

Comment: Is the rest of the path (including the part you've replaced with `...`) the same?

Comment: ya they are the exact same, also the module has a problem with the file:// prefix so I strip it from the url before passing it, but for some reason it just doesn't like the private part. Tried stripping that too, no luck.

Comment: Ok wait I'm dumb it didn't work because RNFetchBlob doesn't like %20 in the urls...